# prompt() command isn't executing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn javascript. Right now I am at a lesson on prompts.

Example 1 works as intended.

Example 2 does not, and there is no error message. An empty window opens and nothing happens.

Both examples are from a book on javascript. Both seem fine in Notepadqq

I'm running them on the same OS and browser(Ubuntu, Firefox)

Since I assume I typed something wrong I already compared it to the source but I can't find my mistake.

Example 1:

```
var yourName = prompt("Please enter your name\nenter:","name");

alert("You entered:\n" + yourName + "\nThank you!");

document.write(yourName);
```

Example 2:

```
var number = prompt("Enter first number:","0");

var n1 = parseFloat(number);

var n2 = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a second number","0");

var sum = n1 + n2;

alert (n1 + " + " + n2 + " = " + sum);
```

Comment: You might be missing a closing paren on line 3 of the second example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 3 was wrong

```
var n2 = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a second number","0");
```

corrected:

```
var n2 = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a second number","0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

youre missing a parenthesis after n2 variable should be, `parseFloat(prompt("Enter a second number","0"));`

Comment: It works now Thanks to all of you. Is there a way to test code in Notepadqq? In Arduino I could always test my code and always found those syntax errors.

Comment: if youre running basic lines such as these, you can do it in your web console. use f12 in most browsers to pull up the console.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error and were missing a parenthesis in `n2`. Here is the correction.

```
var number = prompt("Enter first number:","0");

var n1 = parseFloat(number);

var n2 = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a second number","0"));

var sum = n1 + n2;

alert (n1 + " + " + n2 + " = " + sum);
```